# Durandal: How to pass config data from HTML Host to ViewModel?

Tags: zend-framework, mvvm, knockout.js, viewmodel, durandal

I'm using Zend to generate my main view host.  As such it's the only HTML that is getting parsed on the server side.  My server knows about a config parameter that I want to pass all the way down to one of my viewmodels.  I do NOT want to have the viewmodel request this data via ajax.

How can I have my view pass data through main.js, through the shell, down to my viewmodel in durandal?

Right now i'm setting the value in a nasty global, then referencing that global in my viewmodels in my index.phtml:

```
    <script>
        //This sucks, but i don't know how to pass stuff down into Durandal yet...
        //
        window.ServiceRoot = "<?=$this->contentRoot?>";
    </script>
```

In a straight KO app i would have just passed it over to the KO viewmodel constructor (or set an observable property).

Technically I'm using the durandal 2.0 pre-release but i don't think this matters.  I'm thinking i need to pass parameters via the require.js script tag like I would main params.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you add a config.js module to hold your "Configuration" data. Add an initialize function to get the config data from the server and cache it.

Then... In your shell.js's activate function, initialize the config before binding your views.

You could then require your config module in all your viewmodels and it will only return the cached data.

**config.js**

```
define(['dataaccessmodule'], function (dataaccessmodule) {
    var config =
        {
            serviceRoot: null,
            init: init
        };

    var init= function()
    {
        // get config from server and set serviceRoot;
        // return a promise
    };
    return config;
});
```

**shell.js**

```
define([... your required modules..., 'config'],
    function (..., config) {

        function activate() {
            return config.init().then(boot);
        };
        function boot() {
            // set up routing etc...

            // activate the required route
            return router.activate('home');
        };
});
```

**someViewModel.js**

```
define([... your required modules..., 'config'],
    function (..., config) {
        var someViewModel =
        {
            serviceRoot: config.serviceRoot
        };

        return someViewModel;
    });
```

I know you said that you don't want to load the data via ajax, but using this method, you would only be loading it once and re-using it. You could also load extra configuration if you require. This separates the code nicely using the single responsibility principle.

**Edit:**

If you really need to do it in your rendered page, you can do something along these lines:

```
<script>
var myapp = myapp || {};

myapp.config= (function() {

    var contentRoot = "<?=$this->contentRoot?>";
    return {
        contentRoot: contentRoot
    };
})();
</script>
```

Then, in your main.js, before defining the main module, you can short circuit  it using:

```
define('appconfig', [], function () { return myapp.config; });
```

You can then require the appconfig module in your viewmodel as you normally would and access the contentRoot using appconfig.contentRoot.

Comment: thx for the detailed response, and if it weren't for my conditions it would work rather well.  However i can't "get" my config from the server via ajax because the config is the server URL itself.  The app is hosted on various host/path/subpath and as such the only reliable way to know the root url of services is on the server itself.  that's why the ajax technique won't work for me.  i want to avoid putting discover logic in the JS if possible.

Comment: your edited response is a bit hacky, but much less so then my super global hack.  could you not do the define right in the host page?

Comment: In a typical scenario `require.js` wouldn't be loaded yet, so `define` would be `undefined`. You might try loading `require.js` in the header, then `define('appconfig',  [], function() { return contentRoot = "<?=$this->contentRoot?>"; }) and the last load main.js.

Comment: @RainerAtSpirit:This may just work. Not sure what the impact would be on the SPA though.

ChrisDaMour:Yes, it is a bit hacky, but you'll either have to do that or use Rainer's suggestion.